# Code section is not executed as expected when exported to Excel in SSRS

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

What i am doing here in my code is, I have

```
ID   Value
1    a
1    b
1    c
2    a
2    b
```

and I am getting

```
ID   Value
1    a,b,c
2    a,b
```

I could just do it in the SQL using STUFF keyword but I have decided to go with this

In the code section of the report I have written

```
Private CurrGroupBy As String = String.Empty
Private ConcatVal As String = String.Empty

Public Function AggConcat(GroupBy as String, ElementVal as String) as String
    If CurrGroupBy = GroupBy Then
        If InStr(ConcatVal, ElementVal,0) = 0 Then
            ConcatVal = Trim(ConcatVal) & ", " & ElementVal 
        End If
    Else
        CurrGroupBy = GroupBy 
        ConcatVal = ElementVal 
    End If
Return ConcatVal 
End Function
```

and in one of the rows I am using this expression below

```
=RunningValue(Code.AggConcat(Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Theme.Value), Last, "DataSet1")
```

This is working perfectly if  view the report and export it to PDF. But, when I export it to Excel then the result I am getting is

```
ID   Value
1    a
1    a,b
1    a,b,c
2    a
2    a,b
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you please advise whether this is SSRS 2008 or 2008R2? There are different options for the two versions.

Comment: This is in SSRS 2008R2

Comment: +1 for the `STUFF` keyword, which I never heard of before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried to reproduce what was explained above, both the report viewer and excel produced the described unexpected scenario.

Although in order to achieve the desired output i added a report group and removed the `=(Details)` group this worked both in Report View and when exporting to Excel.

The solution ended up looking like:

[image: SSRS Group Code Solution]

Comment: Thanks Matthew! I have two tablix here in my report, one for excel and one for everything else and I totally forgot about the grouping in excel tablix. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad that it sorted it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue. If the starting code is in excel you could modify this code to do what you want. I found this a long time ago. if it is not what you’re looking for ignore it.

```
Sub ConcatNotesTextV2()
' hiker95, 04/14/2012
' http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=628561
Dim r As Long, lr As Long, nr As Long, n As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For r = 2 To lr
  n = Application.CountIf(Columns(1), Cells(r, 1).Value)
   If n = 1 Then
     'do nothing
  ElseIf n > 1 Then
    Range("B" & r) = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("B" & r & ":B" & (r + n) - 1)), ,)
    Range("A" & r).Offset(1).Resize(n - 1).ClearContents
  End If
  r = r + n - 1
Next r
On Error Resume Next
Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells        (xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete  
On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```